# Send email from Sencha desktop application

Tags: javascript, email, extjs, sencha-touch

We are using Sencha Touch to build an application that can be packaged to run on both a desktop machine as well as mobile devices. The project requires the ability to send emails with attachments from all devices. However, a restriction of the project is we cannot use a backend server to process the data.

Is there any way that I can send an email with an attachment from a Sencha application that doesn't require a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers cannot send email other than the **mailto:** functionality. This action is then passed to the client's mail app, not the browser. You need some form of server-side proxy to do what you want.

`mailto:` functionality is not even well-defined across browsers. See: http://email.about.com/od/mailtoemaillinks/a/mailto_elements.htm

If browsers could send mail then a billion web sites would be hijacking visitor sessions to send spam.

Comment: So there is no way to launch the client's mail app and create a new email containing an attachment? Going through the mail client is fine but we want to improve the user experience by having the attachment ready to go.

Comment: Nope, allowing programmatic mail attachments and sending would be a huge security hole.

Comment: Only if you package your project like a app, then you can use the cordova to send mail using the mobile email app.